# R: prcomp, Order of columns in data table matter?

Tags: r, pca

I ran the prcomp function on a data table containing 91 columns and 2030 rows and obtained a PCA plot. However, when I re-ordered the same data table to make it easier to color-code the data points, I got an entirely different looking PCA plot.

Does the order of the columns matter in prcomp()?

Just a note, the code included was provided for me by someone previously in my lab, who is no longer here to ask. I have a moderate understanding of what it is doing.

Thanks for the help!

[image: PCA Plot #1]

[image: PCA Plot #2]

```
pcaPlotter3d <- function(fileName, startColumn, endColumn){
x<- read.table(fileName, sep = '\t', header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
pcaData <- prcomp(~., x[,startColumn:endColumn], na.action=na.exclude, scale = TRUE)
library(scatterplot3d)
colorList <- c(rep("magenta", 2), rep("blue", 12), rep("red",33), rep("purple", 2), rep("green", 6), rep("black",36))
shapeList <- c(rep(19, 91))#, rep(15, 24))

with (pcaData, { 

pointsForPlot <- scatterplot3d(pcaData$rotation[,1:3], color=colorList, 
                  pch = shapeList, main = "TAP Proteins PCA", mar = c(3,3,3,5), xlab = "PC1 (16.5%)", ylab = "PC2 (3.67%)", zlab = "PC3 (2.79%)",
                  col.grid = NULL)
pointsForPlot.coords <- pointsForPlot$xyz.convert(pcaData$rotation[,1:3])

legend(8,5, bty = "n", xpd = TRUE, cex = 0.75, inset = .1,
    title = "Groups", c("Bio", "EF", "IF", "RF", "Rib", "Unk"),
     col = c("magenta", "blue", "red", "purple", "green", "black") , pch = c(19,19,19,19,19,19));
})
print(summary(pcaData))
}
```

Comment: can you post links to the two plots?  Are your two plots equivalent if you consider reflection around the zero-axes (i.e., flipping left-right or top-bottom)?

Comment: I edited to the question to include the plots. It might be possible that it is a reflection of the data, but if it is, I'm having a hard time seeing it.

Comment: ok, it's probably indeed a different PCA output since the % inertia vary in PC2 and PC3

Comment: @agenis, I'm wondering if the apparently different inertias in the axis labels are a typo.  Are the axis labels generated automatically or are they hand-coded?  The ranges of PC2 (-0.1 to 0.5 in plot 1, -0.5 to 0.1 in plot 2) and PC3 (-0.2 to 0.4 in plot 1, -0.4 to 0.2) support the flipping hypothesis ... can we see the code (and, ideally, the data) ? ... 3D perspective makes it especially hard to tell if axes are flipped. A 2D representation might be easier.

Comment: Good idea, but i think it's more *probable* that one the 91 variable has been skipped or taken twice during the preprocessing, that would slightly modify the coordinates and %inertias

Comment: just another remark: is it 91 rows OR 91 columns?

Comment: 91 columns (protein samples) with 2030 rows (interaction proteins)

Comment: axis labels/inertia values look hardcoded.  How can they differ between plots???

Comment: I changed them. I separately printed the "Proportion of variance" for the different PCs and then input them by hand. I double checked that they were different between the two tries, but apparently I needed to triple check them I feel like an idiot. They are the same between the two, so it must be a rotation. I apologize for taking your time and thank you for helping find my mistake.

Comment: you could easily flip the signs on PC2 and PC3 by hand (i.e., just multiply them by -1 within the code ...)

Comment: good guess, @BenBolker ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see in the perspective plots, but it seems that all that has happened is that the signs of PC2 and PC3 have been flipped.  (Eigenvectors/PCA directions are only defined up to a change in sign, and a trivial change like changing the order of the columns can indeed cause them to flip.)  Given that the inertias/proportions of variance are the same and the ranges of the axes are inverted (e.g. PC2 goes from -0.1 to 0.5 in plot 1 and -0.5 to 0.1 in plot 2), this is the most likely explanation.  You can simply multiply the PC2 and PC3 coordinates by -1 in the appropriate places if you want to recover the original plot ...